# Custom Post Type Title Placeholder

Tags: title

Is it possible to use custom placeholder for custom post title?

I couldn't see any placeholder mentioned in the `labels` array argument of `register_post_type` [function documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes sure you can achive that simply using `enter_title_here` filter hook.

```
    add_filter('enter_title_here', 'my_title_place_holder' , 20 , 2 );
    function my_title_place_holder($title , $post){

        if( $post->post_type == 'portfolio' ){
            $my_title = "Add new Portfolio";
            return $my_title;
        }

        return $title;

    }
```